# Tree structure of data in REST - URL always from root?

Tags: api, rest, tree, restful-url, restful-architecture

#### Problem

When the data have a tree structure of parent/child/grandchild entities, we often duplicate the information in the URL, specifying parent IDs, even if that's not necessary. What's the best way to design the RESTful API in such case? Can the URLs be shortened and the parent IDs omitted?

---

#### Example

The tree is as follows: The top-most entity is a product. Each product has 0-N reviews. Each review can have 0-M comments attached. In theory, there can be an arbitrary depth of this tree.

The naive RESTful API would look like this (assuming only GET endpoints):

```
/products ... list of products
/products/123 ... specific product 123
/products/123/reviews ... list of reviews for product '123'
/products/123/reviews/abc ... specific review 'abc'
/products/123/reviews/abc/comments ... list comments for review 'abc'
```

Hang on, wait a minute... The last two labels I have written do not say anything about product '123'. Yes, the review 'abc' belongs to that product, but as a human, I don't need to know that. And if the review ID 'abc' is unique among *all* reviews, neither does the computer.

So for example when we send an update (PATCH) request for review 'abc', we don't need to know whole hierarchy of parent objects up to the tree root (products), e.g that it belongs to product '123' in this case. Of course, we assume each object has an unique ID among all objects of that entity - but that's a natural behavior for example in RDBs, so many people (well, their APIs) are in this situation.

---

#### Questions

1. If the IDs of "child entities" are unique among all entities of that type, would it be best practice to design the API like this?

   ```
   /reviews/abc ... specific review 'abc'
   /reviews/abc/comments ... list comments for review 'abc'
   /comments/xyz ... specific comment 'xyz'
   ```
2. If answer to (1) is yes, should an endpoint like this be valid as well? Why? Why not?

   ```
   /products/123/reviews/abc/comments/xyz ... specific comment 'xyz'
   ```
3. If short URLs are allowed (or even preferred), isn't this a bit inconsistent then?

   ```
   /products/123/reviews ... list reviews for product '123'
   /reviews/abc ... specific review 'abc'
   /reviews ... what should be here? all reviews?
   ```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Depends - I wouldn't recommend it, but if you find a use case for it, why not?
3. I see no inconsistency - yes, in this situation `/reviews` should be a list of all reviews in system, but if that makes no sense for your application, then `/reviews` can just yield a 404 and everything's fine.

---

Ideally, design of URLs should be decoupled from the rest of the REST API. That means, as far as your URLs are uniquely identifying your resources, they're (from purely theoretical point of view) "well designed".

But API is an interface and it should be treated as such. API is consumed by machines, but those machines are written by people, so in fact, design matters. It's the same reason why to have nice URLs on your blog - there is no technical reason for it, but it improves the experience of users if they want to read, share, remember or understand your URLs (you may say that Google searches for keywords in URLs and so it is a technical reason, but no, it's not - Google's bot is just one of your users - website consumers - and optimization for the bot is just like any other optimization for your users, thus it's interface design).

---

In case design of your URLs matters (for any reason), then in my opinion the best approach is to keep them simple. As simple, as you can. Your observation is very right - you don't need to mimic hierarchy of your resources or the way you store data in database. Eventually it would only get in your way and in a way of people who want to consume your API.

If a resource is uniquely identified within a collection by an ID, then design your URLs just `/collection/{id}`. Look how Facebook does it - majority of its API does exactly this. Structure of their URLs is pretty flat.

There doesn't even need to be a `/collection` resource for listing all existing objects. You can have them linked only from places, where it makes sense, like `/products/123/reviews`, where you can list links pointing to `/reviews/{id}`.

### Why I think complicated URLs are bad?

#### Relations between resources are graphs and you can't put graphs to URLs

Putting other IDs and hierarchies into URLs makes things more complicated for no reason. Usually, hierarchies are not so simple in APIs - relations between resources are more often very complicated graphs, not simple trees. So don't put linking between resources into your URLs - there are better places (hypermedia formats, link headers, or at least [linking by ID references](http://jsonapi.org/)) where to put information about relations and those are not limited to one string like URLs, so with them you can define relations better.

#### You're torturing your consumer by requesting too much parameters

By requiring more information in URL from consumer, you force him to remember all this context and all those IDs or know those values in advance. You require more (unnecessary) input, but in reality, there is no reason for consumer to remember product's ID just to check out one of its reviews.

#### Evolvability

In case your URLs are not decoupled well, you should really think of what happends if structure of your data changes in time. With simple URLs, nothing really happens. With complicated URLs, every time you change the way your API resources are related, you'll need to change also URLs so they keep up with your structure. And as everyone knows, changing URLs is hard - whether we are talking about web or APIs. Hypermedia somehow solves this, but even without hypermedia you can do at least so little that you keep your URLs light and as change-prone, as it gets.

### Your design could look like this

- `/products/{id}` - specific product, links to an endpoint with list of its reviews
- `/products/{id}/reviews` - lists links to endpoints of reviews of the product
- `/reviews/{id}` - specific review, should link to reviewed product and it could even link to the list above, if it seems to be useful for an API consumer

In fact, any of those resources can also link to any other thing in the system, if its useful or if there is a logical connection. Some linking systems (such as hypermedia) make understanding those links easier, because you can specify a `rel` attribute, which says to consumer where the link is pointing to (`self` points to itself, `next` could point to another page, etc.).

---

Of course, as always, it depends on your specific case. But generally, I'd recommend to keep URLs decoupled and simple. Also, I wouldn't recommend to to try to mirror any complicated relations or hierarchies in URLs.

Comment: That's a good answer. For getting resources, it makes very good sense. What about creating one? If I want to create a new review, should I `POST` to `/reviews` or `/products/123/reviews`? Of course, the review belongs to the product 123, but as you mentioned, it can have more than just one relationship. What would you advice?

Comment: It's really up to you. Both ways are valid and you can even support both. The second way seems to be more logical if you have no `GET /reviews`, but relationship to product is being set by something in URL, which can complicate things. Neither seems to generally stand out and be "better way".

Answer (score 0):

As long as the URL can uniquely identify the resource, it is correct.

So the approaches in both Q-1) and Q-2) are fine to use and can be mixed.  It is like provide different entry points to the same resource.

The answer to the question comes back to your business use-case.  If there is no need for more than one entry points, should just stick with one and it will simplify the code.

To Q-3,  ‘/reviews’ will mean all reviews.  Also you don’t need to support that if there is no business use-case to get all reviews in your system.

Hope this help.